# C# emgu saving an emgu captured image to a MySQL database

Tags: c#, mysql, blob, emgucv

I am able to convert the emgu image format to a byte string and this does save on the MySQL database with this code, but the image is saved in a format not even recognized by windows image viewer

```
            string myConnection = mydbconnection;

            MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);

            myConn.Open();

            Bitmap image = trained.ToBitmap();

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

            image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);

            byte[] picture = ms.ToArray();

            string formmattedPic = Convert.ToBase64String(picture);

            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO sql434250.facialid (timeanddate,photo1) VALUES(@named,@Trainedface)",myConn);

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@named", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = named;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Trainedface", MySqlDbType.Blob);
            cmd.Parameters["@Trainedface"].Value = formmattedPic;


                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    label4.Text = named.ToString();

                    myConn.Close();
                }
```

My problem starts when I try to add the final image formatting I get a `system not supported` exception on the `fs = new FileStream(named, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);` line, I am not sure how the filestream works, (new to C#) so please forgive me for any obvious mistakes in the code, for information I am on a windows 8 os, vs 2013

as here:

```
            FileStream fs;

            BinaryReader br;


        byte[] ImageData;



       **fs = new FileStream(named, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);**

        br = new BinaryReader(fs);

        ImageData = br.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);

        br.Close();

        fs.Close();




            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO sql434250.facialid   (timeanddate,photo1) VALUES(@named,@Trainedface)",myConn);

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@named", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = named;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Trainedface", MySqlDbType.Blob);
            cmd.Parameters["@Trainedface"].Value = ImageData;


                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I am able to take converted  images saved on my pc and manually download via the MySQL site the images these images do work with the software, so to my shame I know its a coding error.

added database table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `**yourdatabase**`.`facialid` (
`id` int( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`timeanddate` varchar( 30 ) NOT NULL ,
`photo1` longblob NOT NULL ,
`code1` varchar( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
`code2` varchar( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
`code3` varchar( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
 PRIMARY KEY ( `id` )
```

added full form code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using Emgu.CV.CvEnum;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;


namespace MultiFaceRec
{
public partial class FrmPrincipal : Form
{
    //Declararation of all variables, vectors and haarcascades
    Image<Bgr, Byte> currentFrame;
    Capture grabber;
    HaarCascade face;
    HaarCascade eye;
    MCvFont font = new MCvFont(FONT.CV_FONT_HERSHEY_TRIPLEX, 0.5d, 0.5d);
    Image<Gray, byte> result, TrainedFace = null;
    Image<Gray, byte> gray = null;
    Image<Gray, byte> trained = null;
    Image image1 = null;
    List<Image<Gray, byte>> trainingImages = new List<Image<Gray, byte>>();
    List<string> labels= new List<string>();
    List<string> NamePersons = new List<string>();
    int ContTrain, t;
    string name, names = null;


    public FrmPrincipal()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //Load haarcascades for face detection
        face = new HaarCascade("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml");
        //eye = new HaarCascade("haarcascade_eye.xml");
    }
    public void dbconnection()
    {

        grabber = new Capture();
        grabber.QueryFrame();
        //Initialize the FrameGraber event
        Application.Idle += new EventHandler(FrameGrabber);

        try
        {
            //Load of previus trainned faces and labels for each image

            string myConnection = **"youdbconnection"**
            MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);
            MySqlDataAdapter myAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
            int totalrows = 0;
            int rownumber = 0;

  MySqlCommand SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand(" select * from     **yourdb**.facialid ", myConn);

             MySqlDataReader myReader;

            myConn.Open();

            myReader = SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();

            int count = 0;
            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                count = count + 1;

                string id = myReader.GetString("id");
                string Labelsinfo = myReader.GetString("timeanddate");
                string picdata = myReader.GetString("photo1");
                string LoadFaces;

                LoadFaces = myReader.GetString("photo1");
                byte[] picData = myReader["photo1"] as byte[] ?? null;



               ImageConverter pic = new ImageConverter();
               Image img = (Image)pic.ConvertFrom(myReader["photo1"]);
               Bitmap bitmap1 =  new Bitmap(img);


                trainingImages.Add(new Image<Gray, byte> (bitmap1));
                labels.Add(Labelsinfo);

                rownumber = count +1;
                totalrows = count;
                ContTrain = count;
                //string userid = myReader.GetString("id");
                //string useron = myReader.GetString("user");
}
            myReader.Close();
                myConn.Close();

            label2.Text = totalrows.ToString();


        }
        catch(MySqlException ex)
        {

            //MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
          int errorcode = ex.Number;
            MessageBox.Show("Nothing in binary database, please add at least a  face(Simply train the prototype with the Add Face Button).", "Triained faces load",  MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            //Trained face counter
            ContTrain = ContTrain + 1;

            //Get a gray frame from capture device
            gray = grabber.QueryGrayFrame().Resize(320, 240,  Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_CUBIC);

            //Face Detector
            MCvAvgComp[][] facesDetected = gray.DetectHaarCascade(
            face,
            1.2,
            10,
            Emgu.CV.CvEnum.HAAR_DETECTION_TYPE.DO_CANNY_PRUNING,
            new Size(20, 20));

            //Action for each element detected
            foreach (MCvAvgComp f in facesDetected[0])
            {

               trained =  currentFrame.Copy(f.rect).Convert<Gray, byte>();
                TrainedFace = currentFrame.Copy(f.rect).Convert<Gray, byte>();

                break;
            }

            //resize face detected image for force to compare the same size with the 
            //test image with cubic interpolation type method
            TrainedFace = result.Resize(100, 100, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_CUBIC);

            //string image;

            //Show face added in gray scale
            imageBox1.Image = TrainedFace;


            string named = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss:ms");

            string myConnection = **"your db connection"**

            MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);

            myConn.Open();

            Bitmap image = trained.ToBitmap();

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

            image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);

            byte[] picture = ms.ToArray();

            string formmattedPic = Convert.ToBase64String(picture);


            FileStream fs;

            BinaryReader br;


        byte[] ImageData;



       fs = new FileStream(named, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

        br = new BinaryReader(fs);

        ImageData = br.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);

        br.Close();

        fs.Close();




            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO **yourdb**.facialid  (timeanddate,photo1) VALUES(@named,@Trainedface)",myConn);

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@named", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = named;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Trainedface", MySqlDbType.Blob);
            cmd.Parameters["@Trainedface"].Value = ImageData;


                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    label4.Text = named.ToString();

                    myConn.Close();
                }


        catch (MySqlException ee)
        {
            int errorcode = ee.Number;

        }
        }


    void FrameGrabber(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label3.Text = "0";
        //label4.Text = "";
        NamePersons.Add("");


        //Get the current frame form capture device
        currentFrame = grabber.QueryFrame().Resize(320, 240,  Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_CUBIC);

                //Convert it to Grayscale
                gray = currentFrame.Convert<Gray, Byte>();

                //Face Detector
                MCvAvgComp[][] facesDetected = gray.DetectHaarCascade(
              face,
              1.2,
              10,
              Emgu.CV.CvEnum.HAAR_DETECTION_TYPE.DO_CANNY_PRUNING,
              new Size(20, 20));

                //Action for each element detected
                foreach (MCvAvgComp f in facesDetected[0])
                {
                    t = t + 1;
                    result = currentFrame.Copy(f.rect).Convert<Gray,  byte>().Resize(100, 100, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_CUBIC);
                    //draw the face detected in the 0th (gray) channel with blue color
                    currentFrame.Draw(f.rect, new Bgr(Color.Red), 2);


                    if (trainingImages.ToArray().Length != 0)
                    {
                        //TermCriteria for face recognition with numbers of trained  images like maxIteration
                    MCvTermCriteria termCrit = new MCvTermCriteria(ContTrain, 0.001);

                    //Eigen face recognizer
                    EigenObjectRecognizer recognizer = new EigenObjectRecognizer(
                       trainingImages.ToArray(),
                       labels.ToArray(),
                       1000,
                       ref termCrit);

                    name = recognizer.Recognize(result);

                        //Draw the label for each face detected and recognized
                    currentFrame.Draw(name, ref font, new Point(f.rect.X - 2, f.rect.Y - 2), new Bgr(Color.LightGreen));

                    }

                        NamePersons[t-1] = name;
                        NamePersons.Add("");


                    //Set the number of faces detected on the scene
                    label3.Text = facesDetected[0].Length.ToString();

                    /*
                    //Set the region of interest on the faces

                    gray.ROI = f.rect;
                    MCvAvgComp[][] eyesDetected = gray.DetectHaarCascade(
                       eye,
                       1.1,
                       10,
                       Emgu.CV.CvEnum.HAAR_DETECTION_TYPE.DO_CANNY_PRUNING,
                       new Size(20, 20));
                    gray.ROI = Rectangle.Empty;

                    foreach (MCvAvgComp ey in eyesDetected[0])
                    {
                        Rectangle eyeRect = ey.rect;
                        eyeRect.Offset(f.rect.X, f.rect.Y);
                        currentFrame.Draw(eyeRect, new Bgr(Color.Blue), 2);
                    }
                     */

                }
                    t = 0;

                    //Names concatenation of persons recognized
                for (int nnn = 0; nnn < facesDetected[0].Length; nnn++)
                {
                    names = names + NamePersons[nnn] + ", ";
                }
                //Show the faces procesed and recognized
                imageBoxFrameGrabber.Image = currentFrame;


                //Clear the list(vector) of names
                NamePersons.Clear();

            }



    private void FrmPrincipal_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dbconnection();
    }

    private void label3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void label4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Was just reading another post where a comment asked for the create table code and the full code to test his/her code out will do the same will edit post to add both.

Comment: @alex thanks for the required suggested edits, much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my question, I don't know what I did wrong but with a little copying here and there the following code works, what I have done is first stored the image to a local application file and used this file location in the file stream.

```
             named = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss:ms");
            TrainedFace.Save(Application.StartupPath + "/Temp/face1.bmp");

            string dated = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss:ff dd-MM-yy");
            label4.Text = dated;

            //Show face added in gray scale
            imageBox1.Image = TrainedFace;
            trainingImages.Add(TrainedFace);
            labels.Add(label4.Text);

            byte[] imagepic = null;
            FileStream fsstream = new FileStream(Application.StartupPath + "/Temp/face1.bmp", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fsstream);
            imagepic = br.ReadBytes((int)fsstream.Length);

            string myConnection = "datasource=sql4.freemysqlhosting.net;port=3306;user=sql434250;password=lE3!lQ5*";
            MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);
            MySqlCommand SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO `sql434250`.`facialid` (`id`, `timeanddate`, `photo1`) VALUES (NULL, @dated, @IMG);", myConn);
            MySqlDataReader myReader;

                myConn.Open();
                SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@IMG", imagepic));
                SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@dated", dated));
                myReader = SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();

                while (myReader.Read())
                {                    
                }
```